# Insert Into table with a join based on certain parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My Table looks like the following:

```
      TableA

ID    |SEQ |CODE
======|====|=========
Item1 |1   |A
Item1 |2   |B
Item2 |1   |A
Item2 |2   |B
Item2 |3   |C
Item3 |1   |B
Item4 |1   |C
```

Each `ID` goes up 1 in `SEQ` for each `CODE` it has applied, depending on the order in which it was applied. I am trying to add more data to this table for a new code, and want to add it for a certain set of items from a second table, as the most recent sequence number for that item. What I have so far

```
Insert Into TableA
Values(TableB.ID, 
(Case when TableA.SEQ = '1' and Count(TableA.ID) = 1 then '2'),
'E')
From TableB
Join TableA on TableA.ID = TableB.ID
Where TableB.E_ADDED = 'Y' and
TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

This code obviously doesn't work, and I can't think of a word or phrase to describe what I'm trying to do to search it, so I figured I would ask.

Comment: Well first of all when you are inserting data from another table you need to do INSERT...SELECT, and not INSERT...VALUES.

Comment: Can I do an INSERT...SELECT while also putting in my own value at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can include constants in the SELECT list.   INSERT...SELECT ColA, 'A Constant Value' FROM ...

Comment: It's hard to understand how you would like insert the data. Could you please give an example of the data you would like to insert, and how the TableA should looks like after that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question but you can say what's wrong with this try.

```
Insert into TableA
(ID, Seq, Code)
Select TableB.ID, 
       Seq2 = isnull((select max(TableA.Seq)+1 from TableA where TableA.ID=TableB.ID),1),
       TableB.Code
From TableB
```

Comment: Ok, if an `ID` has 3 entries into the table, it's `SEQ` should read 1 on the first entry, 2 on the second entry, and 3 on the third entry. I want to insert new entry for multiple `ID's` based on the `ID's` from `TableB = TableA`, with the correct `SEQ` number for the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your requirement (with few assumptions), hope the below helps

```
CREATE TABLE #SO_32400879 (ID NVARCHAR(10),SEQ NVARCHAR(10), CODE NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #SO_32400879 VALUES ('Item1','1','A')
INSERT INTO #SO_32400879  VALUES ('Item1','2','B')

INSERT INTO #SO_32400879  VALUES ('Item2','1','A')
INSERT INTO #SO_32400879  VALUES ('Item2','2','B')
INSERT INTO #SO_32400879  VALUES ('Item2','3','C')

INSERT INTO #SO_32400879  VALUES ('Item3','1','A')

INSERT INTO #SO_32400879  VALUES ('Item4','1','A')


CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID NVARCHAR(10), CODE NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item1','C')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item1','D')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item1','E')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item2','D')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item3','B')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item4','B')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Item4','C')


INSERT INTO #SO_32400879 (id,SEQ,CODE)
SELECT t.ID,(SELECT MAX(s.SEQ) FROM #SO_32400879 s WHERE s.ID= t.ID ) + ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS SEQ, t.CODE 
FROM #Temp t

SELECT * FROM #SO_32400879 ORDER BY 1,2
DROP TABLE #SO_32400879 
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

And the Output is as below :

```
ID   |SEQ|CODE
=====|===|==
Item1|1  |A
Item1|2  |B
Item1|3  |C
Item1|4  |D
Item1|5  |E
Item2|1  |A
Item2|2  |B
Item2|3  |C
Item2|4  |D
Item3|1  |A
Item3|2  |B
Item4|1  |A
Item4|2  |B
Item4|3  |C
```